# How to get an email when new key is created in Firebase real time database

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Well, I have looked almost everywhere, and apparently there is Firebase Cloud Functions which can be used to send me an email whenever a new key is created in my database. However, I cannot wrap my head around where to start and how to do it. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Are you sure you want an email *every time a new node is created*? That could be potentially a *lot* of emails. Wouldn't it be better that your app receive a childAdded event for nodes you are interested in or perhaps a notification? Can you provide a use case? There is an answer which may very well be correct but  the use case should be considered.

Comment: At first I want an email because I know there won't be a lot of keys that would be created.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use a Cloud Function to send an email each time a new node (i.e. a new key) is created in the database.

Have a look at the documentation for Realtime Database triggers [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) and at one of the official Cloud Functions sample which shows how to send an email, [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js).

In the sample, emails are sent in response to the creation and deletion of user accounts, but it is really not difficult to integrate the sample code with a Realtime Database trigger.

For example you could do something like the following, adapted from the sample:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
// For Gmail, enable these:
// 1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
// 2. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
// TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

// Your company name to include in the emails
// TODO: Change this to your app or company name to customize the email sent.
const APP_NAME = 'xxxxxx';

exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.database.ref('/thePathYouWant/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

       const createdData = snapshot.val(); // data that was created

       const email = createdData.email; // The email of the user. We make the assumption that it is written at the new database node
       const displayName = createdData.displayName; // The display name of the user.

       return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
});

// Sends a welcome email to the given user.
async function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: email,
  };

  // The user subscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. I hope you will enjoy our service.`;
  await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
  return console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
}
```

If you are totally new to Cloud Functions for Firebase, it is probably a good idea to follow the tutorial [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) and to watch the official video series, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/).