# Firebase realtime database trigger android with email notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

Hi I'm developing an android application of hospital management system. I want to add an appointment system in that. Is there any possibility that when patient make appointment the doc get email and msg of the appointment. Please help

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101368/how-to-get-an-email-when-new-key-is-created-in-firebase-real-time-database/53101676#53101676

Comment: Sir is that applicable to android java project also?

Comment: It is independent from the front-end technology, as it uses Cloud Functions, which are code snippets which run on the Firebase back-end infrastructure.

Comment: Thankyou so much sir I'm grateful to you